# How to get current url dynamically with python

Tags: php, python

I'm a baby in python coding. I have found some similar questions and answers but i still can't solve the problem.
I know some PHP codes that can get current url through server information,e.g:

```
$protocol = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off' || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https://" : "http://";
$url = "$protocol$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

How could python do the same thing?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you need this? In general you don't, since there's a way to tell the browser to do the right thing.

Comment: Python has this cool library called BeautifulSoup4, which is great for harvesting all sorts of data from a webpage. I'm sure it could get the URL, though I've never used it.

Comment: Umm...I'd like to invoke the JSSDK API of WeChat(a kind of IM tool) so that I need certification signature which is generated partly from current url. WeChat has offered some PHP examples where the annotation added to "get url" says: 'you should get URL dynamically, don't write hardcode.' 
I think "the current url" represents the path of my script on a cloud server.@Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams